# How to remove String from display

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem.
I don't know how to remove String from my display (only this which state of ToggleButton is Off).

```
public class Cal extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        display.setText("Wybierz produkty");
    }

    static boolean isempty = true;

    public void changeButton(View sender) {
        ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) sender;

        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) sender).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            if (isempty) {
                if (btn.getText().toString().equals("0"))
                    return;
                display.setText(btn.getText());
                isempty = false;
            } else {
                display.append(btn.getText());
            }
        } else {
            if (btn.getText().toString().equals(btn.getText()))
                display.setText(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

`display.setText(" ");` removes everything, but I only want to remove clicked String...
I tried SharedPreferences but I don't know how to do it right.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand very well your code, so maybe your problem is not exactly hiding the view but the logic you are implementing. Anyway, to hide a view you can use `setVisibility`:

```
display.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

---

EDIT:

So, you need to remove the String in the clicked button from the String contained by another TextView?

If that's your question, this is how I'd solve that:

```
String textToReplace = btn.getText();
String currentText = display.getText();

display.setText(currentText.replace(textToReplace, ""));
```

Otherwise, try to explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Now everything in display is gone and I can't add anything else.

Comment: I need to do something like opposite to append. I think you know what I mean, becouse your code seems fine, but my app has stopped.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove a substring from your initial text. Edit your question and paste your exception trace.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the toggle button to false

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
display.setText("Wybierz produkty");
display.setCehcked(false);
}
```